# Use variable of one component in another component in the same file

Tags: angular, dragula, ng2-dragula, angular-dragula

I have two components defined in the **same file**, and am trying to access one variable of a component into another, and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097480/how-to-use-a-variable-from-a-component-in-another-in-angular2)
answer, but the `get SomeValue()` function is not showing up in the other class when I try to refer to it.

Given answer on provided link:

```
export class Demo {
const sum = 10;

get SumValue() {
    return this.sum;
}
}
```

import-->Demo

```
export class Demo2 {
   private sum: number;
   this.sum = Demo.SumValue();
}
```

I can use a shared service, but don't want to use it just for one variable.

Is there something I'm missing from that answer?

Comment: What is relation between those 2 component, for example its siblings or parent-child?

Comment: @R.Viral siblings

Comment: Might be you are missing `@Input()` in template

Answer (score 0):

This is called `Component Interaction`

you need to use `@Input` for this.

If the property you want to send child is changing asyncronously, then you need to use `EventEmitter`

check [this link](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) for reference

here is simple example:

Child Component

```
import { Component, Input  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    template: `<h2>Child Component</h2>
               current count is {{ count }}
    `
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() count: number;
}
```

Parent Component:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
        <h1>Welcome to {{title}}!</h1>
        <button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
        <button (click)="decrement()">decrement</button>
        <child-component [count]=Counter></child-component>` ,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Component Interaction';
  Counter = 5;

  increment() {
    this.Counter++;
  }
  decrement() {
    this.Counter--;
  }
}
```

[Reference](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/passing-data-child-component-angular/)